# How do you select a face loop?

Tags: modeling

Selecting a loop with alt+click only selects vertical faces as shown in picture. How can the horizontal loops be selected? Are there any settings that could influence loop selection?

Blender 3.4.1
Macintosh 12.6.2 (Monterey)
[image]

Comment: Alt+click a bottom or top edge of a face  you will get a vertical loop. Alt+click a right or left edge of a face you will get a horizontal loop.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> takes into account the closest edge you click on to determine the direction of the loop to select. The nearest edge will select a face loop perpendicular to that edge.

Similarly, when selecting edges or vertices, where you click determines the way it selects things.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you very much.